# Column reordering in ADF

Tags: azure

My source delimited csv file has certain columns **col1,col2, col3,col4**.

I want to create another CSV file from my source file with the below column ordering
**Col3,col1,col2,col4**

Is it possible to do in data flow/copy activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change the order of columns while using copy activity as well as data flow.

Simply drag and drop columns (6 dots before every column) to appropriate position and we are done.

[image: ColumnMapping]

Comment: What if there are 300 plus columns .That becomes very manual process.Cant we order alphabetically atleast ?